# Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: /auth/google_auth_code/callback

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

**edit**: [*here is a minimal viable project*](https://github.com/rednebmas/google_auth_code_test)

I am trying to get an access and refresh token from Google from an authorization code for the server-side flow. I followed Google's guide here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow.

I am using using passport and [passport-google-authcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-authcode).

Here are the routes for the node app:

```
router.get('/auth/google_auth_code',
    passport.authenticate('google_authcode', {
        scope:
        [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
            'profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ]
    }),
    function () {
        res.end();
    })

router.get('/auth/google_auth_code/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google_authcode', {
        failureRedirect: '/error'
    }), 
    function (req, res) {
        // do something with req.user
        res.send('hello');
    }
);
```

Here is the passport config for this strategy.

```
passport.use('google_authcode', new GoogleAuthCodeStrategy({
    clientID: 'my client id',
    clientSecret: 'my secret',
    callbackURL: '/auth/google_auth_code/callback',
    // passReqToCallback: true
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, rawResponse, profile, done) {
            // unable to get here
    }
));
```

When an authentication request is made, Google responds with the following error:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: /auth/google_auth_code/callback"
}
```

Here is my credential setup in the Google console:

[image]

At this point I don't know what else to do. I have also tried changing the callback URL in the passport.use to an absolute URL. I am definitely getting back a valid auth code (it looks like: `4/Mb2pcOyhYhziROyFHKH5pnzvUldYbAmMop9SJKbBHXQ`). Let me know if there is any more relevant information that I can provide.

Thanks,
Sam

**edit**

I noticed that I have the URLs ending with a forward slash above. I fixed that, but I have not updated the screenshot.

<s>If I use the full url (e.g. `http://localhost:8080//auth/google_auth_code/callback) I get the following error:</s>

```
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
```

If I use the full url (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/auth/google_auth_code/callback) I get the following error:

```
{
  "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
}
```

Comment: `http://localhost:8080//auth/google_auth_code/callback` why the 2 slash after port number ?

Comment: @SagarV That must be a typo when I added the information to the post. I just doubled checked and with the full (correct) URL I am now receiving a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error. This makes me think you are not supposed to specify the host.

Comment: in authorised `JavaScript origins` , instead of `http://localhost` try `http://localhost/auth` and check if it is working or not @SamB

Comment: The console won't let me add the /auth because `Origin URIs must not contain a path or end with "/": http://localhost:8080/auth`

Comment: I read this. but to make it clear I am asking. Did you exact url with `localhost` instead of this `callbackURL: '/auth/google_auth_code/callback'` ?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it from the credential console as well. If it is helpful, here is the "post_data" from the oauth2 module (note that the client secret, client_id, and the auth code have had many characters removed at random locations in their respective strings) `"grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fauth%2Fgoogle_auth_code%2Fcallback&client_id=xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxxxxxx&code=4%2FExxxxx"`

Comment: @SagarV ok, x'ed them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139820/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-samb).

Comment: i believe you are missing a forwardslash have you tried: `callbackURL: '/auth/google_auth_code/callback',`

Comment: @GeomanYabes by copying and pasting, that's the exact URL I'm using above (copy-past and find on the page). If you see in the edit I mention that the URL in the screenshot has a forward slash in it, but I have removed that without updating the screenshot. Thanks for idea!

Comment: sorry, i mean: `callbackURL: '/auth/google_auth_code/callback/'` in your JS code.. to match your setting in your google console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be passport-google bug, as you may see it here: 
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/issues/21

What they suggest in this issues to use: https://github.com/sqrrrl/passport-google-plus

Its how open source works, you have to either fix it your self or find another package.